# How to resolve Jekyll non www to www on 000-default.conf in apache

Tags: apache, jekyll, virtualhost

Switched from wordpress to Jekyll and trying to resolve nonn www to www. Running on ubuntu 14.04.

When I change `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` with the following in the vhost it works but I get `/html` sub folder added to the domain. Have I implemented this correctly if so, how do I get rid of it?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName undesired.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com notthis.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, was missing `DocumentRoot` in vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```